# R Anytime NA is it an error?

Tags: r

I'm wondering what does it mean if anytime() returns NA. I'm using a machine learning algorithm to predict time. Now, I want to compare the time, my prediction gave me minus the target. So I end up with 1823584.590, and if i do anytime(1823584.590), it returns NA

Comment: Have you read `?anytime`? Check to see what values it expects. NA means missing value.

Comment: in which package is the function `anytime`?